# How to call a create service from axios post

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

How to call a `create` service from an axios post in `Register.js`. I have added the proxy settings in package.json file >> "proxy": "http://localhost:3000".

```
node v12.16.2 
axios : 0.19.2
react: ^16.13.1
```

//
    1. Created 'http-common.js' file under src folder

```
import axios from "axios";

const http = axios.create({
 baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/',
 headers: {
"Content-type": "application/json"
 }
})

export default http;

2. Created `services/RegisterService.js` under services folder



   import http from "../http-common";
    const create = data => {
       return http.post("/register", data);
    };

    export default create;
```

Register.js react component:

```
import RegisterService from '../services/RegisterService';
const Register = () => {

   const [register, setRegister] = useState({ _id: '', profileImage: '', firstName: ''})

   const onChange = (e) => {
    e.persist();
    setRegister({...register, [e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
   RegisterService.create(register)
    .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response)
     })
    .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error)
    }) 
  }

  return (
        <div className="register_player_Twocolumn_layout_two">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="myForm">
            <div className="formInstructionsDiv formElement">
              <h2 className="formTitle" >Sign Up</h2>
              <div className="register_profile_image">
                <input id="profilePic" name="profileImage"  type="file" onChange={onChangePicture} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="fillContentDiv formElement">
              <div className="names formContentElement">
                <input className="inputRequest " name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name" onChange={onChange}/>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="submitButtonDiv formElement">
              <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Register</button>
            </div>
         </form>
       </div>
  );
}
export default Register;
```

Comment: Do you default export the `const axios` from "htt[p-commons.js" file? I mean, is variable `http` in "services/RegisterService.js"  the axios instance you created in htt[p-commons.js?

Comment: I will check that soon.

Comment: I haven't default export the `const axios`. I did that now. Then I have imported axios in RegisterService.js as follows `import axios from "../http-common"; ` then instead of http i have changed to axios >> `const create = data => {
       return axios.post("/register", data);`
    };

Comment: @KarthickVinod >> Is this what you want me to change ?

Comment: Yes. Did that help? If not, can you edit the question to reflect the changes you just made

Comment: @KarthickVinod not yet mate.., should i need to restart the server ?

Comment: give restart a try. Also what is the issue here? Request is not being made?

Comment: I have updated my question now, now while submitting the post from `Register.js` it throws error xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/register 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

Comment: Should i need to import the`RegisterService.js` into the `Register.js` where `Register.js`  is my react component ..?

Comment: I have also updated with the Register.js component in my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213840/discussion-between-karthick-vinod-and-soccerway).